# transpose column to row oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a query returned value in this form (query return more than 50 columns).

```
 1-99transval  100-200transval  200-300transval ... 1-99nontransval 100...
   50              90                 80                  67           58
```

For a row value. I want these details to be converted into columns and take the following shape:

```
Range       Transval      NonTransval
1-99        50            67
100-200     90            58
```

Comment: I very much doubt that you can do this without dynamically generated and executed SQL, which means a program to drive it.

Comment: Do you need all of the ranges in the output, or just the two shown?

Comment: all the range i need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure **SQL**, it will need a lot of coding because you will have to manually put the **range** as there is no relation between the values and the range at all. Had there been a relationship, you could use **CASE** expression and build the range **dynamically**.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT 50 "1-99transval",
  3      90 "100-200transval",
  4      80 "200-300transval",
  5      67 "1-99nontransval",
  6      58 "100-200nontransval",
  7      88 "200-300nontransval"
  8    FROM dual
  9    )
 10  SELECT '1-99' range,
 11    "1-99transval" transval,
 12    "1-99nontransval" nontransval
 13  FROM DATA
 14  UNION
 15  SELECT '100-200' range,
 16    "100-200transval",
 17    "100-200nontransval" nontransval
 18  FROM DATA
 19  UNION
 20  SELECT '200-300' range,
 21    "200-300transval",
 22    "200-300nontransval" nontransval
 23  FROM DATA;

RANGE     TRANSVAL NONTRANSVAL
------- ---------- -----------
1-99            50          67
100-200         90          58
200-300         80          88
```

From **Oracle database 11g Release 1** and above, you could use **UNPIVOT**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT 50 "1-99transval",
  3      90 "100-200transval",
  4      80 "200-300transval",
  5      67 "1-99nontransval",
  6      58 "100-200nontransval",
  7      88 "200-300nontransval"
  8    FROM dual
  9    )
 10  SELECT *
 11  FROM   DATA
 12  UNPIVOT( (transval,nontransval)
 13  FOR RANGE IN ( ("1-99transval","1-99nontransval") AS '1-99'
 14                ,("100-200transval","100-200nontransval") AS '100-200'
 15                ,("200-300transval","200-300nontransval") AS '200-300'));

RANGE     TRANSVAL NONTRANSVAL
------- ---------- -----------
1-99            50          67
100-200         90          58
200-300         80          88
```

Above, in your case you need to replace the **WITH** clause with your existing query as a **sub-query**. You need to include other columns in the **UNION**.

In **PL/SQL**, you could (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** and get the "range" by extracting the **column names** in **dynamic sql**.

Although, it would be much better to modify/rewrite your existing query which you have not shown yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle 11g version then you can use the UNPIVOT feature.

```
CREATE TABLE DATA AS
SELECT 50 "1-99transval",
    90 "100-200transval",
    80 "200-300transval",
    67 "1-99nontransval",
    58 "100-200nontransval",
    88 "200-300nontransval"
  FROM dual


SELECT *
FROM   DATA
UNPIVOT( (Transval,NonTransval) FOR Range IN ( ("1-99transval","1-99nontransval") as '1-99'
                                            ,("100-200transval","100-200nontransval") as '100-200'
                                            ,("200-300transval","200-300nontransval") as '200-300'))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9747/3/0